# How to set selected item for Spinner in Android

Tags: java, android, drop-down-menu, android-spinner

In an Android app, I have a `SpinnerAdapter` that I am using to display expiration years of credit cards. My variable `expirationYears` contains an array of Strings with years from `"2020"` to `"2029"`. It was declared as `String[] expirationYears = new String[10];` and then with a function I set the ten years as Strings, from current year and then the nine subsequent years after that for a total of ten elements in the array. When I run it, this is what I see:

[image]

Everything is perfect so far. The only problem is that when as you see in the image above, `2020` is the year selected by default. That is the first element in the `expirationYears` array. But I want to set `2021` as default (the second element of the array). This is what my code has:

```
Spinner spinnerYearCreditCardPayment;
SpinnerAdapter creditCardYearAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter(Payment.this, expirationYears);
creditCardYearAdapter
    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerYearCreditCardPayment.setAdapter(creditCardYearAdapter);
spinnerYearCreditCardPayment
    .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        ..........
    });
```

I was expecting to have some property available to define which element I want to show by default. Something like `creditCardYearAdapter.setSelectedItem(INDEX_NUMBER)`. But that property does not exist. Do you know how I could set the default selected item so that it is not the first element of the array (2020) but the second (2021)? Thank you.

**UPDATE 1:**

Following The_Martian's answer, this was what I did:

```
spinnerYearCreditCardPayment
    .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
           arg0.setSelection(1);
           cardYear = (String) spinnerYearCreditCardPayment
               .getSelectedItem();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

Now I correctly see the second element of the array ("2021") as the default selection.

The problem is that when I use `arg0.setSelection(1);`, I choose another year and it does not respond. The selected year remains "2021" even thought I am trying to change the year.

Comment: Store the id of elements in int[] too , this will enable to use both value and the field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do similar to the following. I am just giving you an idea here.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                 parent.setSelection(position + 1);  
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet

```
  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
    {
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) 
         {

               int seleccion=parent.getSelectedItemPosition();
                spinner.setSelection(position)
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the spinner item based on value instead of position. Can refer the example below-

```
String value = "to be selected value";
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.select_state, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
if (value != null) {
    int spinnerPosition = adapter.getPosition(value);
    mSpinner.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
}
```